# expectation of $X,Y$ RV's and $Y>0$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

suppose I have 2 independent random variables $X,Y$, and $Y>0$, also suppose that $Z=\frac{X}{Y}$ and $\mathbb{E}[Z]$ exists and $0<\mathbb{E}[Z]<1$ what of the following has to be correct?

1. $\mathbb{P}[X\leq Y]=1$
2. $\mathbb{P}[0\leq X]=1$
3. $\mathbb{P}[0\leq X\leq Y] > 0$
4. $0\leq \mathbb{E}[X] \leq \mathbb{E}[Y]$

how can i even approach this question? i've tries using chebichev and markov inequalities but nothing came out of it.

Comment: Take $Y$ to be a constant random variable like $2$. Then any choice of $X$ is independent of $Y$. Use this to contradict $(1)$ and $(2)$. Use contradiction to prove that $(3)$ is true. I believe that $(4)$ is not true, but am not able to find a counterexample.

Comment: Hint $\frac{X}{Y}=X.\frac{1}{Y}$. Using $X,Y$ independence, try to compute.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron You're assuming that $E[X],E[Y]<\infty$. I am not sure if this is true.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer You're correct. Also I wrote $1/E[Y]$ instead of $E[1/Y]$ .

Answer (score 0):

4. is correct. Actually denoting $a= E(Y)$ and $b=E(\frac{1}{Y})$ we observe that $$0\leq E\left(\left(\sqrt{\frac{Y}{a}}-\sqrt{\frac{Y^{-1}}{b}}\right)^2\right)$$         implies that $1\leq ab$ (this is Schwarz inequality) therefore $E(|Z|)<1$ implies
   $$E(|X|) \leq \frac{1}{E(\frac{1}{Y})}\leq E(Y).$$